# How to compress DailyLogFile after rotation?

Tags: python, twisted

I currently have twisted managing rotating the log files for my application, however the logs are becoming large and I'd like to look at compressing them when they rotate.

I've done a quick look through the twisted docs and don't see how I can do this with the [`DailyLogFile`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/api/twisted.python.logfile.DailyLogFile.html) class.

My setup for logging is:

```
from twisted.python.log import ILogObserver, FileLogObserver
from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile
...
"Setup the logging"
logPath = os.getcwd() + "/logs/"
logFile = DailyLogFile("lazarus.log", logPath, defaultMode=0644)
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, FileLogObserver(logFile).emit)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `DailyLogFile` and overload the `rotate` method:

```
class DailyCompressedLogFile(DailyLogFile):
    def rotate(self):
        super(DailyCompressedLogFile, self).rotate()
        newpath = "%s.%s" % (self.path, self.suffix(self.lastDate))
        if os.path.exists(newpath):
            # compress newpath here
```

Comment: See also an existing implementation of this, http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/727